# VS2012 Data Source Configuration Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2012, datasource

I sounds silly, but I can't get the "Data Source Configuration Wizard" opened in Visual Studio 2012.
Can anyone show me how to do it?

Update:

I can't find Project -> Add New Data Source, this is my PROJECT menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Tools -> Connect to Database
Or perhaps Project -> Add New Data Source

Comment: Hi Mary, which version of 2012 are you using? So I can check and update my answer for you.

Comment: Hi Louis, I have a Ultimate 2012 version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL.